# F# What is the difference between the abstractclass and abstractclassattribute

Tags: f#, attributes

F# What is the difference between the [`<AbstractClass`>] and [`<AbstractClassAttribute`>], both seem to label a type as abstract.

[`<AbstractClass`>]
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483471.aspx

[`<AbstractClassAttribute`>]
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370513.aspx

Comment: They're the same thing, just documented in two different places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference, they both refer to `AbstractClassAttribute`.  In F# (and C#), you can optionally omit the `Attribute` suffix when attaching an attribute with `[<AttributeName>]`.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233179.aspx#Anchor_1

Note that if you wished to refer to the attribute in normal code, you'd have to use the full name.

```
let example = AbstractClass() // ERROR
let example = AbstractClassAttribute() // OK
```